# Can't load multiple languages with r.js and i18n require plugin

Tags: internationalization, requirejs, r.js

I have my 3 files

- /nls/home.js
- /nls/root/home.js
- /nls/fr/home.js

/nls/home.js file contains the basic

```
define({
  "root": true,
  "fr": true
});
```

And a define in my main js file like so

```
define([
  'i18n!nls/home'
], function(copy) {
 ...
});
```

It works fine with requirejs but when I use r.js to bundle a single main.js file, I get the error

```
Uncaught Error: undefined missing nls/fr/home
```

in the requirejs function called "main"

If I add the french file to my define

```
define([
  'i18n!nls/home'
  'i18n!nls/fr/home'
], function(copy) {
  ...
});
```

It seems to work.

Do I really need to define all the different language? Thats seems problematic, if I have 20 translations, I'll need to define 20 files everywhere?

Comment: I have the exact same problem... Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, It was for a mobile app so I ended up only loading a single language, the one used on the phone of the user.

Answer (score 0):

In order to inline i18n resources into the built file with rjs, you need to set the locale in your [module config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-moduleconfig). If no locale is specified, i18n resources will not be inlined. Only one locale can be inlined for a build.

Comment: This is a little old but I have the same problem. Doesn't loading only one language at a time completely defeat the purpose of i18n? Or can it access non-inlined versions of the file? Maybe I need a separate module *per language*? I'm definitely missing something here...